# Handle JSON data with a non-fixed format

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

Usually when working with JSON, you'll get a JSON object that has a known and specified format. So if, for example, we're working on a site that lists movies with their title and rating, you have JSON data that looks like:

```
{
    {
        "title": "Inception",
        "rating": 4
    },
    {
        "title": "The Dark Knight",
        "rating": 5
    },
    etc...
}
```

In Javascript, looping through this JSON is easy by doing:

```
for (let i = 0; i < movies.length; i++) {
    console.log('The title: ' + movies[i][0]);
    console.log('The rating: ' + movies[i][1]);
}
```

But what if you get a JSON object that doesn't have a predefined format as the one above. The JSON in the example consists of multiple objects that all have two properties called title and rating. Because the structure/format is known, it's easy to just loop through it accordingly. But when a single JS code has to loop through JSON that doesn't have predefined format, how can I know how to loop through it? For example, what if a user can put unlimited objects within objects without my code not knowing what it has to do with it?

I'm trying to make a simple application that transforms JSON into HTML. With HTML (which is similar to XML), you as a developer, can choose how many elements you want to put inside of each other. Different mark-ups have completely different formats, with some people nesting lots of elements while others don't use many nested elements, etc. How can I handle the same thing as HMTL parsers handle, but with JSON?

I've tried writing at least a little bit of code to start with, but I just get stuck when I realise that the code really has to be able to handle any sort of format.

What kind of logic do I need to implement to understand this? I'm not asking for a piece of code that'll do all this for me, but I'd like to know how people approach a problem like this and what kind of tricks can be used to implement this.

Comment: You're talking about an [AST](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_syntax_tree) in json format?

Comment: If you're trying to do something like [JSONView](https://jsonview.com/), you may want to have a look at its [source code](https://github.com/bhollis/jsonview/).

Comment: You need depth first search for this which will start from your json object as parent and will go through all nodes inside of it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can simply use `Object.keys` function. it's return array of keys in the objects. then you loop throw this array

**Or**

You can use `for .. in`.

Example:

```js
let user = {
  name: "Me",
  age: 100,
  website: "http://stackoverflow.com"
};

for (key in user){
  console.log(key," ", user[key])
}
```

**Update:** if you want to loop over array with non fixed format objects recursively. see this example using `Map` array function

```js
let myMap = function (arr){  
 arr.map((obj) => {
        for (key in obj){
            if ( obj[key] instanceof Array){
                myMap(obj[key])
            } else {
                console.log(key, " ", obj[key])
            }
        }
 })

}

let myArr = [{
  name: "Me",
  age: 100,
  website: "http://stackoverflow.com"
},
{
  name: "You",
  age: 99,
  questions: [{"q1": "How are you ?"}, {"q2": "What is your name ?"}]
}
]

myMap(myArr)
```

Comment: This is not a complete solution as it only handles one data type, and is not recursive.  This a piece of the puzzle for sure, but not a complete answer to the question.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to write some recursive logic that knows how to handle each data-type that can be passed into it. Let's split that into two categories: object and non-object.

If the data-type your parser comes across is non-object (i.e. number, string, array, etc), then presumably you know how to handle it. If your parser comes across an object, that should trigger the starting of the function again (within its current execution). This may seem like a long and potentially performance-heavy option, but I see no other way of drilling down into arbitrarily many layers of JSON data.